Show that every set of positive measure in $R^n$ must contain a basis for $R^n$
The intuition comes from the fact that every open set in $R^n$ must contain a basis for $R^n$. Now, I want to extend this to a set of positive measure. But I don't know how to start it.

Hint:  Consider a counterexample and let $V$ be its span, which must then be a vector space of dimension $<n$.  Derive a contradiction.

oh, right! any subspace of $R^n$ with dimension less than $n$ must be measure zero. Thanks

Now I get it. Thanks for lulu's hint. I'll show it by contradiction. Let $S\subset R^n$ be a set of positive measure. Suppose $S$ does not contain a basis for $R^n$. Then, $S$ must lie in a subspace $V$ of $R^n$ and $\dim(V)<n$. Then, $m(S)\leq m(V)=0$ implies that $S$ is measure-zero. A contradiction.
